# OpenGL placing planes

Tags: android, opengl-es, translation, rotation, surfaceview

I'm trying to create a SurfaceView that contains a GLView showing 9 planes.
I'm trying to get planes oriented in a diamond shape around the origin. Essentially it will have the top layer all point in towards the origin at a 120 degree angle separated in a circular shape by 120 degrees. The middle layer will also be separated by 120 degrees but be perpendicular to the x axis and parallel to the y. The bottom layer will be an inverse of the top layer.

So far I have tried loops (didn't end well, the planes were scattered across creation) and going by plane by plane to make sure that the yaw and pitch were properly set. Neither have worked.

If you have any ideas please tell me or point me in the direction of a decent tutorial.

Thanks
~Aedon

Here is my line by line code snippet:

dyaw & dpitch: 120 degrees

w & h: width(2) and height(3) accordingly

spacing: .5f

```
// Top Layer
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mGL.glRotatef(dpitch, 0, 0, 1f);
mGL.glTranslatef(0, h + spacing, 0);
mPanels[0].drawColorful(mGL);
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mPanels[1].drawColorful(mGL);
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mPanels[2].drawColorful(mGL);
// Middle Layer
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mGL.glRotatef(-dpitch, 0, 0, 1f);
mGL.glTranslatef(0, -(h + spacing), 0);
mPanels[3].drawColorful(mGL);
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mPanels[4].drawColorful(mGL);
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mPanels[5].drawColorful(mGL);
// Bottom Layer
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mGL.glRotatef(-dpitch, 0, 0, 1f);
mGL.glTranslatef(0, -(h + spacing), 0);
mPanels[6].drawColorful(mGL);
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mPanels[7].drawColorful(mGL);
mGL.glRotatef(dyaw, 0, 1f, 0);
mPanels[8].drawColorful(mGL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found a much better tutorial [from INsanity](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/). If anyone has any OpenGL question for android take a stab with this guys tutorials, they are fantastic.

~Aedon